# Encrypt alfresco password

Tags: alfresco

I want to encrypt **db.username** and **db.password** written in alfresco-global.properties . 
Can anyone please help me in this, where that username & password is used so that i can write decryption code there, so that alfresco can understand.

I am using Alfresco 4.2 Enterprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just change permissions on alfresco-global.properties so only the user running the Alfresco JVM can read it ?

Anyways, that said the values are used in `tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/core-services-context.xml`. Create a custom bean `baseDefaultDataSource` deriving from org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and handle the decryption in that class. Make sure to pass the decrypted value to the jdbc driver. Also make sure the definition gets processed after the defaults kick in. You might want to drop your spring context into `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension`.